# Is FileChannel position(long newPosition) 0-indexed?

Tags: java, channel, java.nio.file

That is, if I do:

```
channel.position(0)
channel.read(buffer); // will read in 1st byte of file and so on
```

vs

```
channel.position(1)
channel.read(buffer); // will read in 2nd byte of file and so on
```

Are my assumptions correct? Reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position(long)) doesn't really say anything about that so I wanted to make sure

Answer (score 1):

> Is FileChannel position(long newPosition) 0-indexed?

Yes.

> Reading the documentation doesn't really say anything about that so I wanted to make sure

It is clear to me.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#position--) for `position()` says:

> *"Returns: This channel's file position, **a non-negative integer** counting the number of bytes from the beginning of the file to the current position".*

"[A] non-negative integer" means zero or greater.  If they had meant one or greater, they would have written "a positive integer" or "a strictly positive integer".

Answer (score 0):

The method is 0-indexed.

Also when you call the read method, then the file position is updated with the number of bytes actually read. The channel’s position() method returns the current position.